# How to quote an numbered equation in a paper

Tags: mathematical-writing

In a research paper, when one quotes a numbered equation, is it necessary to put the definite article *the* in front of *equation* like "the equation (3.2)", or is it ok to omit *the* and simply write "equation (3.2)"?

Comment: Peter's answer is correct. It is also commonplace to leave out "equation" as well, as in "it follows from (3.2) that...".

Comment: "*an* numbered"?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay However, some papers use separate numbering sequences for equations, proclamations, and/or subsections, so that in addition to an equation 3.2 there might be a theorem 3.2 and a subsection 3.2.  So I would probably recommend putting in the "equation" for clarity.

Comment: @MikeShulman The parentheses in (3.2), which also appear on the equation label, serve to distinguish.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay In theory, yes, but I still think additional clarity can be given by including the word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ordinary English it is correct to omit the definite article 'the' because 'equation (3.2)' serves as the proper name for the equation.